# Anaconda Prompt Instead of PS in Microsoft Visual Code

Tags: python, anaconda

Just installed Anaconda3. It came with the Microsoft Visual Code editor. I would like to use the Anaconda Prompt instead of Powershell or the CMD window from within the editor. Is there a way to change the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find the exact answer I was looking for but I believe my solution may help others so I'm posting my workaround:

Conveniently the Windows CMD or Powershell terminal opens in the same directory as the folder loaded into the Visual Code editor so I wanted to maintain this functionality. Here is how I did it without changing any Environmental Variables.

First change the default terminal from within Visual Code to the CMD terminal instead of Powershell. Add the following code to a batch file.

```
call "c:\anaconda3\Scripts\activate"
```

Then I named the batch file and saved it to my root directory. In my case `snake.bat`. Now when I launch my CMD terminal I just type `c:\snake.bat`and the CMD prompt changes into an Anaconda prompt.

The Visual Code Editor attempts to do this already, but has errors. I believe this is because it opens with Powershell instead of the CMD terminal by default.